# Adding ‘active’ class in ng-repeat on hover

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello I have the following code:

```
div( ng-repeat='cladding in claddings track by $index' ui-sref='app.protected.docInside.cladding({documentId, claddingId: cladding.id})')
   div(ng-if='!cladding.deleteFlag')
       .doc-child-img
       p {{cladding.name}}
       element-dropdown(type='"cladding"')
       .clearfix
   del(ng-if='cladding.deleteFlag')
       .doc-child-img
       p {{cladding.name}}
       element-dropdown(type='"cladding"')
       .clearfix
```

How can I set to div(ng-if='!cladding.deleteFlag') and del(ng-if='cladding.deleteFlag') 
ng class ‘active’ on hover??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can register the new event to the DOM element

ng-mouseover && ng-mouseleave with ng-class

take the current hover item then add property to it likes 'hover'

here the example 

`div( ng-repeat='cladding in claddings track by $index' ui-sref='app.protected.docInside.cladding({documentId, claddingId: cladding.id})')
   div(ng-if='!cladding.deleteFlag')
       .doc-child-img
       p {{cladding.name}}
       element-dropdown(type='"cladding"')
       .clearfix
   del(ng-if='cladding.deleteFlag',ng-mouseover="cladding.hover=true",ng-class='{myClass:!!cladding.hover}',ng-mouseleave="cladding.hover = false")
       .doc-child-img
       p {{cladding.name}}
       element-dropdown(type='"cladding"')
       .clearfix`